# SVG with dynamic content as background image

Tags: svg

I understand that the  tag in SVG is mainly used for events, but I rather need it for avoiding the need to repeat code, like the following case:

```
<script>
    var i=0,c1=0xf80,c2=0xf40,X,n=8; while(n) {
        X=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","text");
        X.setAttribute("x",65-i); X.setAttribute("y",80+i); X.setAttribute("class","txt");
        X.setAttribute("fill","#"+(c1.toString(16))); X.innerHTML="e";
        document.rootElement.appendChild(X);
        X=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","text");
        X.setAttribute("x",90-i); X.setAttribute("y",86+i); X.setAttribute("class","txt");
        X.setAttribute("fill","#"+(c2.toString(16))); X.innerHTML="f"; 
        document.rootElement.appendChild(X);
        n--; i++; c1+=16; c2+=16;
    }
</script>
```

But if I want to use the SVG as background image, the  tag for some reason NOT EXECUTING, leading me to change the above code to something stupid that looks like this:

```
<text x="65" y="80" class="txt" fill="#f80">e</text>
<text x="90" y="86" class="txt" fill="#f40">f</text>
<text x="64" y="81" class="txt" fill="#f90">e</text>
<text x="89" y="87" class="txt" fill="#f50">f</text>
<text x="63" y="82" class="txt" fill="#fa0">e</text>
<text x="88" y="88" class="txt" fill="#f60">f</text>
<text x="62" y="83" class="txt" fill="#fb0">e</text>
<text x="87" y="89" class="txt" fill="#f70">f</text>
<text x="61" y="84" class="txt" fill="#fc0">e</text>
<text x="86" y="90" class="txt" fill="#f80">f</text>
<text x="60" y="85" class="txt" fill="#fd0">e</text>
<text x="85" y="91" class="txt" fill="#f90">f</text>
<text x="59" y="86" class="txt" fill="#fe0">e</text>
<text x="84" y="92" class="txt" fill="#fa0">f</text>
<text x="58" y="87" class="txt" fill="#ff0">e</text>
<text x="83" y="93" class="txt" fill="#fb0">f</text>
```

Everyone looking at the code above can see how stupid is this repeat...
Just for a quite simple task, I really doubt there is no better way of doing it.
Just imagine more complicated situation, **I will need to end up with tousands of lines for nothing**......

If anyone know of a way to handle repeating objects (or better **doing "loop" tasks**), please let me know here.

Thanks a lot in advance.:)

Comment: SVG does not run script if you display it as an image i.e. via a background-image.

Comment: This I saw, but any other way (or other scripting way) to achieve such complicated shapes for making SVG as image?

Comment: you could create a data URI and then use that as an image.